# Samsung S3511 - Driver for tje integrated graphics card

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, resolution

I had to replace my HDD. I have installed windows and most of the drivers from samsung website(http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP-S3511-S01UK-downloads) . It looks that there is a driver missing for the screen. When I go to the resolution options the screen comes up as Generic PnP monitor and resolurion of 1024x768 even though my real screen resolution is 1366 x 768. Has anyone came across this problem before?

Comment: Did you install the chipset driver?

Comment: Yes I have installed chipset driver

Comment: Open device manager and see what your graphics driver looks like http://imgur.com/a/Niuzb Sometimes you'll need up with Microsoft Basic Display driver instead of the correct one that enables all features

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Intel site - look for Win7Vista_64_152258. Samsung does not provide a driver - it is part of the Intel setup on the motherboard